# RDP connections directly on remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, credential-providers

Don't know exactly how to phrase this, please bear with me...

I have a credential provider I wrote, and if I set a custom credential filter to only use my credential provider, when I login on the machine, I have to enter an OTP on the "remote desktop" or respond to a push request on an app. That works fine and I'm able to login.

However, if the original username/password are not correct, then the credential provider never gets loaded and we never get a chance to re-enter on the "remote desktop" because the login is rejected at a lower level.

I've been thinking about one time tokens in our system for remote logins and so this being unable to connect without the correct username/password is a stumbling block. If my credential provider never gets loaded since the whole remaining login flow is blocked upstream by Windows, I cannot use a one time token as I have dreamed it.

I honestly don't know if I'm being blocked by my RDP client (mstsc) or something on the remote machine I am trying to connect to. I would guess more towards the remote machine...but really, I don't know.

Is there a registry setting I could try to bypass for now so that my credential provider would always get loaded? Or, is there a way to hook into whatever blocks it and maybe write a COM component with hooks into our web service that would permit/block a one-time token I'm envisioning?

Comment: if logonui.exe started - all registered credential providers and filters is loaded. probably you fail on NLA level

Comment: Try to trace your provider load/unload events.

Comment: Also try to temporarily disable the NLA.

Comment: @Alexander When you say disable the NLA? You mean the advanced setting for Remote Desktop Server? Disable setting requiring Network Level Authentication to work? I tried that...didn't work. I created a version of CredPro/Filter that logs when it gets created. Only gets loaded after a valid username/password gets sent, and then the CredPro dance begins where I end up having to enter OTP or approve push. Without a valid credential set to begin with, CredPro never gets loaded to begin with.

Comment: @Alexander Found another setting I needed to change. So both you and RbMm are correct in that it was blocked by NLA. I can get past that ... but, now not sure I want to ... LOL There's a reason it exists...right? A security reason...

Comment: If you can continue with disabled NLA it means that we have missed some step. It is just for test scenario.

Comment: Well, if I disable NLA (registry settings), then I can get to the point where I'm logging in on the desktop no matter what my creds might be entered into the RCP client. So, then my CredPro is loaded because I am on the Windows desktop on the login screen--remotely. Most potential customers will have NLA enabled, so my idea of a one time token will fail...unless I can somehow get past NLA. I can write a CredPro that could turn a one-time token into serialized creds, but NLA blocks getting that far. Options seem either: 1) disable NLA, 2) replace/hook NLA. Don't know if 2 is possible?